# Can't enroll in Android Beta Program

Tags: nexus-5x, android-beta-program

I am trying to access the [Android Beta Program page](https://www.google.com/android/beta) with my mac and even my Nexus 5X but as soon as I am presented with a signin screen and I enter my password to continue, I get redirected to an empty page and the Android Beta Program page doesn't load up...
I get a link something like https://www.google.com/android/beta?rapt=AEjHL4MMqsgJ4vq0c0LVX_BLkuayM7BPEP4z9GO8Bp7O2uk4L1pZNAaX9YYdGgzu-3kWI-aBhqxCmAuESj-vnVQShIyTVaVV-g and then nothing happens. I just get a white screen on the browser...

Can someone please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when an Android version is out of Beta, the website portal is closed. If you would like more information, you can take a look here: https://plus.google.com/+SiddhantPagariyaCS/posts/AMHdvN6hPbU

Thanks,
Sid.